# Multiple JOIN in Pig Latin

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hiveql

In HQL, we have

```
JOIN weather ON (weather.Year = flight.Year AND weather.Month = flight.Month and weather.Day=flight.DayofMonth)
```

In Pig Latin, is it possible to fit it into one query? Or I have to do it separately and combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible see [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#join_basic) :

> You can also join on multiple keys. In all cases you must have the
>   same number of keys, and they must be of the same or compatible types

Example :

```
weather = load '/weather/files/' as (Year,Month,Day,Fieldx);
flight = load '/flight/files/' as (Year,Month,Day,Fieldy);
jnd   = join weather by (Year,Month,Day), flight by (Year,Month,Day);
```

Comment: What if (JOIN weather ON (vac.stationid = weather.ID AND weather.Year = flight.Year AND weather.Month = flight.Month and weather.Day=flight.DayofMonth))

Comment: @不好笑 : fields names are not important, the first key will be joined with the first of the other relation and so on !